# Using a good SQL query instead of PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a page that is taking a kind of long time to load, and I'm almost sure that this is caused by too many sql requests (AKA caused by my bad SQL skills). Is there anyway to join these 3 queries into one?

What I want to do with this query is to try to select a specific id from cardapios and, if there is anything there (if $num_rows > 0) the only thing I want to do is select that id. If there is nothing there, then I want to insert something and then select the id of that.

```
    $query = "SELECT id FROM cardapios WHERE nome='$nome'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if ($num_rows > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                $_SESSION['id_cardapio'] = $row['id'];
      $num_rows = 0;
    }}else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO cardapios (nome, kcal, semana)
            VALUES('$nome', '$kcal', '$semana')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            $query = "SELECT id FROM cardapios WHERE nome='$nome' ";
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                $_SESSION['id_cardapio'] = $row['id'];
            }
      }
```

I am trying to put all of this into one query but getting nowhere. Is there anyway to use just one query for doing all of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one query is impossible -- you could put it in a stored procedure.

Comment: I'll look into that, but are you certain that is impossible? I was trying to do this with the IF statement in SQL - but no success.

Comment: If you are using an if statement then it will be more than one query.

Comment: Yes I am certain... you want to do an insert and a select.  THESE ARE DIFFERENT QUERIES.  There is no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the last query by getting the `mysqli_insert_id($con);` as you already have the insert id available after the insert

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM cardapios WHERE nome='$nome'";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $_SESSION['id_cardapio'] = $row['id'];
        $num_rows = 0;
    }
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO cardapios (nome, kcal, semana)
        VALUES('$nome', '$kcal', '$semana')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if ( $sql !== false) {    // did insert work
            $_SESSION['id_cardapio'] = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        } else {
            // insert did nto work??
        }
}
```

Comment: That works 100% - it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a great help, THANK YOU! I'll just wait a few minutes to see if someone can do this in one query - if no one can, I'll select this as answer

Comment: @PedroMartinsNovaes it cannot be done in a single query; you could "insert if missing" in one, but you cannot "select from an insert".

Comment: I understand now. This as select as right answer. Thank you guys.

Comment: Can I do the "insert if missing" and then select inserted id using the php presented on this answer?

Comment: You could do an insert if missing (if you have a unique key on `nome`) with `INSERT IGNORE` or INSERT ... `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, and then use your original SELECT to retrieve the id as normal. _However, unless you expect a lot of "misses" over the life of the project, that would actually mean more query executions in the long run; as you'll be doing a lot on unnecessary `INSERT IGNORE`s that your original code would've prevented._